# How do I get one of these codes to draw a smiley face of varying sizes in a window?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm missing important criteria here to get several smiley faces to appear in various sizes in a window.  I'm new at this and I cannot figure out how to accomplish this on my own.  These are the 2 codes I've created and failed with so far.  Can someone please show me what I am missing to complete the program?

Program 1:

```
from graphics import *

def CreateWindow():
    window = GraphWin("Smiley Faces", 400, 400)
    window.setBackground("light blue")
    window.setCoords(0, 0, 400, 400)
    return window

def drawFace(center, size, win):
    face = Circle(Point(100, 50), size)
    face.setFill("yellow")
    face.draw
    Leye = Circle(Point(90, 60), size)
    Leye.setFill("black")
    Leye.draw
    Reye = Leye.clone()
    Reye.move(20, 0)
    Reye.draw
    mouth1 = Line(Point(80, 40), Point(90, 30))
    mouth1.draw
    mouth2 = Line(Point(90, 30), Point(110, 30))
    mouth2.draw
    mouth3 = Line(Point(110, 30), Point(120, 40))
    mouth3.draw

def main():
    center = 0
    size = 0
    win = CreateWindow()
    drawFace(center, size, win)


    message = Text(Point(100, 10), "Click anywhere to Quit")
    message.draw(win)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

Program 2:

```
from graphics import *

def drawFace(center, size, win):
    face = Circle(Point(100, 50), 30)
    face.setFill("yellow")
    face.draw(win)
    Leye = Circle(Point(90, 60), 5)
    Leye.setFill("black")
    Leye.draw(win)
    Reye = Leye.clone()
    Reye.move(20, 0)
    Reye.draw(win)
    mouth1 = Line(Point(80, 40), Point(90, 30))
    mouth1.draw(win)
    mouth2 = Line(Point(90, 30), Point(110, 30))
    mouth2.draw(win)
    mouth3 = Line(Point(110, 30), Point(120, 40))
    mouth3.draw(win)

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Smiley Faces", 400, 400)
    win.setBackground("light blue")
    win.setCoords(0, 0, 400, 400)
    for size in range(1, 5):
        size = 0
        center = Point(150, 100)
        drawFace(center, size, win)


    message = Text(Point(100, 10), "Click anywhere to Quit")
    message.draw(win)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

I need to write a function to meet this specification.

drawFace(center, size, win) center is a Point, size is an int, and win is a GraphWin.  Draws a simple face of a given size in win.

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://painrinya.com/coding/python-program-intro-computer-science/chapter6ex13-15.php).